# Check Kafka client connection status at runtime

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I built a Java Kakfa client using the library [Apache Kafka 2.8.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.8.0). Sometime, when the Kafka server become unreachable for some reasons, the Kafka log keeps to print over and over again (approximately every 25 seconds), this WARN:

```
[WARN ][NetworkClient] - [[Consumer clientId=ROMLAPA275, groupId=aws-group-internal] Connection to node -1 (serverhost.internal.net/10.95.12.12:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.]
[WARN ][NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater] - [[Consumer clientId=ROMLAPA275, groupId=aws-group-internal] Bootstrap broker serverhost.internal.net:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected]
```

It isn't an Exception, so I cannot catch it. Is there a way to check the connection status in order to do something when the client cannot reach the Kafka server?

I tried to get something in debug and I found the connect status in this path:
[image]

and I think it means there is a wrong status, but I can reach it in debug.

Anyone know how can I do this?
Thanks!

Below the code.

This is the Kafka client class, as a **Thread**:

```java
    public KafkaConsumerLoop(int id, String groupId, List<String> topics, String serverConfig, Context context, String clientId) {
        this.topics = topics;
        this.context = context;
        
        System.out.println("Instanciate Kafka consumer:");
        System.out.println(" - server: "+serverConfig);
        System.out.println(" - topic: "+this.topics);
        System.out.println(" - clientId: "+clientId);
        System.out.println(" - groupId: "+groupId);
        
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, serverConfig);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
        
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        
        this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        System.out.println("Kafka consumer instanciated");
    }
```

I run it in another class:

```java
    /** Create and run consumer as a Thread*/
    private void consumer() {
        Context context = (Context)ContextStore.get().clone();
        context.setProject(this.getProject());
        
        kafkaConsumerLoop = new KafkaConsumerLoop(
                1, 
                this.groupId, 
                Arrays.asList(topicConsumer), 
                this.bootstrapServersConfig, 
                context,
                CLIENT_ID);
        
        kafkaConsumerThread = new Thread(kafkaConsumerLoop);
        kafkaConsumerThread.setName("consumer_thread_"+kafkaConsumerThread.getId());
        kafkaConsumerThread.start();
    }
```

as a loop:

```java
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.consumer.subscribe(topics);
            System.out.println("Consumer running on topic: "+topics);
            System.out.println("Current consumer thread name - "+Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    +" - ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = null;
            while (!closed.get()) {
                records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                records: for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

                    System.out.println("Current consumer thread name - "+Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            +" - ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    String clientId = ""; 
                    
                    // If the header contains the own producer Client ID, skip this message
                    for (Header header : record.headers())  {
                        if(header.key().equals(KafkaClientCommunication.CLIENT_ID_HEADER_KEY))
                            if(new String(header.value()).equals(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName())) {
                                BmsCommon.LOG.debug("Received message from us...");
                                continue records;
                            } else {
                                clientId = new String(header.value());
                                System.out.println("Received message from client-id: "+new String(header.value()));
                            }
                    }
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a rebalance listener?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understood. What do you mean with "rebalance listener"?  By the way, thanks for the answer.

Comment: When client cannot connect to brokers, the consumer will rebalance, and you can check that happening rather than catch network exceptions. See javadoc https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html

Comment: Thanks @onecricketeer but I use a consumer whom directly assigns partitions... 

Comment: So? `onPartitionsAssigned` and `onPartitionsRevoked` should still be able to be invoked... If not, then I typically suggest using an external AdminClient instance thread that can "ping" the cluster to check for a bootstrap connection